# how to access a view/element in xaml.cs button event

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage(string username)
        {

            //this.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("123456");
            //var lblUser = new Label { Text = "Username", TextColor = Color.White };
            //var entUser = new Entry { Placeholder = "UserName", TextColor = Color.White, PlaceholderColor = Color.IndianRed };
            //var lblHello = new Label { Text = ("Hello "+ username), HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
            var lblPicker = new Label { Text = "Label" };
            var datePicker = new DatePicker {};
            var timePicker = new TimePicker {};
            var btnDetails = new Button { Text = "Details"};
            var lblDetails = new Label { };
            
            btnDetails.Clicked += giveDetails;
            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(30),
                Children = {
                    lblPicker,
                    datePicker,
                    timePicker,
                    btnDetails,
                    lblDetails,
                }
            };
            //            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public void giveDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // *i want to set a label value here*
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the element of page in Click Event , you need to define the label as a global property of the ContentPage .

```
Label lblDetails ;

 public HomePage ()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //...
    this.lblDetails = new Label { };
    //...       
}
```

And you can access or set its value in anywhere of the ContentPage

```
public void giveDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.lblDetails.Text = "xxx";  
}
```